# Язык Swift(не могу решить задание на codewars)

Tags: swift

Этот код не выполняется должным образом. Попытайтесь понять, почему.

```
import Foundation

func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {

return a / b
​
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В консоли пишет это: Test Results:
SolutionTest
testMultiplyInts
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("0.3333333333333333") is not equal to ("3.0") +/- ("1e-07") -
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("-0.3333333333333333") is not equal to ("-3.0") +/- ("1e-07") -
Completed in 0.759ms
testMultiplyDoubles
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("0.3666666666666667") is not equal to ("3.3") +/- ("1e-07") -
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("-0.5") is not equal to ("-4.5") +/- ("1e-06") -
Completed in 0.115ms
Completed in 0.874ms

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так. multiply это умножение, а также функция требует возвращение Double, поэтому нужен return.

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}
```

Comment: Если функция состоит из однострочного выражения, то return не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что выше, сказано верно: Multiply переводится как "умножение", а если функция должна что-то вернуть, но тело состоит из одной строки, то слово "return" не нужно, поэтому конечный ответ на ваш вопрос выглядит так:

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    a * b
}
```